# Time series decomposition results interpretation

Tags: r, time-series, arma, multiple-seasonalities, decomposition

I have a long multi-seasonal time series, and the `stl()` decomposition got me this:

[image]

The remainder is definitely not white noise. Then what should be the next step to decide the model?

Try the model with ARMA error term? but it seems that the `stl()` decomposition of the remainder term still get non-WN remainder, which confused me.

```
remainder  <- demand.stl$time.series[,3]
plot(stl(remainder,s.window="p"))
```

Comment: Did you do an STL decomposition on the remainder that you obtained from STL decomposition? That should be avoided. The first decomposition separated the seasonal, trend and remainder components. You need not look for seasonality or trend in the remainder component by running STL on it. You could try modelling the remainder as an ARMA process, though.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks. I was thinking about model the remainder with ARMA. Since the time series can be decomposed as Y=S+T+R, if Y is remainder here, do I need to make sure the remainder of the remainder is WN?

Comment: Seasonal decomposition didn't work. Too much noise in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a rather glaring Christmas effect. I'd recommend either running a [regression with ARIMA errors](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) or, if your [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities) are serious enough, regressing the Christmas effect out and running `tbats()` on the residuals. Then look again at the residuals.

If the residuals still exhibit similar structure as above, you may want to consider GARCH models to model the conditional heteroskedasticity. However, it seems to me like modeling the Christmas effect might already take care of a lot of the heteroskedasticity.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind explaining more about how you tell the Christmas effect from the above decomposition plot and what do you mean by regressing it out?  Add dummy variable? My aim is actually to forecast the whole series (use `tbats()` maybe), but I was thinking about do I need to make sure the remainder is WN before fitting the mode. If the remainder performs like other series, can I forecast the remainder separately, and simply add the trend and seasonal on.

Comment: There is a high probability that your residuals will have/exhibit seasonal structure as you are using an assumed model than a "crafted model" based upon the statistical fingerprint from  your data. If the residuals don't exhibit "seasonality" this will be probably due to the masking effect ("Alice in Wonderland") caused by anomalies/level shifts/multiple trends/changing error variance/changing parameters that you have assumed away. Note that these features (untreated) increase the error variance thus providing an unwarranted  downwards bias to tests of model augmentation.

Comment: The Christmas effect is visible in the sharp drop at the end of each year in the seasonal component. You could hope that the seasonality takes care of this effect - after all, it's periodic. *However*, I wouldn't hope on this for two reasons: (1) The effect is short and sharp - not the kind of thing that the TBATS Fourier terms can easily deal with. (2) If you look closely, you see "holes" near the end of each year in the residual component, so obviously the seasonal part did *not* remove all the Christmas effect.

Comment: As for dealing with it, it would be best to use one or multiple dummy variables. You'd need to look deeper into your data around Christmas to see whether a ramp-up (or -down) makes sense, and of what length. However, `tbats()` does not take external regressors. So I'd regress your raw data on appropriate Christmas dummies or ramp-ups, then model the residuals from this regression using `tbats()` or whatever.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks a lot.  So in this case, the model would be something like using `tslm()` to model $y= \beta_1 * trend + \beta_2 * season + \beta_3 * dummy +\beta_4 * other  covariates + error$, where the error is then modelled using `tbats()`. I will give it a try. Thanks again.

Comment: @IrishStat  That's true. I already tried different ways to difference the data to remove seasonality or remove trend and also tried different models (Arima, Fourier, Tbats). The residuals for all models turn out to have significant seasonality. So I think I'd better get back to the raw data, and figure out the remainder thing.

Comment: Why don't you post your data and I will use some software that you can't buy and see if I can (automatically) generate a model that will yield white noise. There is a lot of colored noise in some of the suggestions made to you..

Comment: @IrishStat  Thank you much! Yes, I would like to post the data, but my data is a bit large (half-hourly data from 2011 to 2016). I guess it might be hard to post them here. Any other ways that I can post a large dataset or just send it to you?

Comment: Time series methods i.e. auto-projective are not very useful as the standard error of the acf would be tiny ...thus a mixed model of separately forecasting 48 half hour intervals and daily totals might work. Why don't you email me the one column data set (no missing readings ) in a zip file or post it to the list using dropbox or some free app .I will look at it and suggest a reformatting so that I can use "toys" at my disposal to integrate.both daily forecasts and 1/2 hour forecasts.